# in python, how to make this code case insensitive

Tags: python

This code delete the line that contains specific word (bad word) 
the problem is case sensitive

for example : it will delete 'printed pillow' but will not delete 'Printed pillow' or 'pRinted PilloW'

any simple fix to make it (case insensitive)

Regards

```
bad_words = ['printed pillow', 'decalac', 'pandora']

with open('oldfile.csv') as oldfile, open('newfile.csv', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `upper`:

```
if not any(bad_word.upper() in line.upper() for bad_word in bad_words):
```

This uses `upper` twice in case either of them is lowercase.

Comment: Why making both uppercase if words in list are lowercase?

Comment: The point of doing it to both is that in case *either* has lowercase/uppercase letters, they become indistinguishable from each other. So it doesn't matter now what you or the user enter, it'll still match.

Comment: It's generally safer to use `casefold` instead of `upper` or `lower` for case-insensitive comparisons. `casefold` handles stuff like [Eszett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) and other weird case distinctions better.

Answer (score 0):

Make it lowercase and then check for your bad words.

```
bad_words = ['printed pillow', 'decalac', 'pandora']

with open('oldfile.csv') as oldfile, open('newfile.csv', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line.lower() for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```